# White screen is shown after backing web page

Tags: php, osx-mavericks

I have developed a web site for booking cars but my problem is in Mavericks when u use the touch pad to back the page a white screen is shown and u have to refresh the page. The back button works fine btw.

here is a scenario:

User open the booking page,select date and time click booking. user is redirected to a proccess.php file with Post method.after doing some magic! data is inserted into database then using header('Location:finish.php'); user will be redirected to another page. in that page when user uses touch pad to back the page in the url the booking.php is shown but the screen is white.

### any idea?

Submit code:

```
<form method="post" action="action/procces.php" id="mfrm">
            <select name="time" id="time" onchange="getinst()">
                <option value="">Select time</option>
                <option value="1">8:00</option>
                <option value="2">9:30</option>
                <option value="3">11:00</option>
                <option value="4">12:30</option>
                <option value="5">14:00</option>
                <option value="6">15:30</option>
                <option value="7">17:00</option>
                <option value="8">18:30</option>
            </select>
<select name="trans" id="trans">
                <option value="1">Automatic</option>
            </select>
<select name="duration" id="duration" onchange="getinst()">
                <option value="">Select duration</option>
</select>

            <input name="package" value="<?php echo $db->res['package_id']; ?>" type="hidden" readonly />
            <input type="submit" onclick="showwait()" name="booksub" class="blue-btn" id="sbm" value="Book Now" disabled="disabled">

  </form>
```

Return:

```
header('Location: ../userarea.php');
```

P.S: This only happens in safari

Comment: Any console errors ? Also how are you submitting the form.. Some relevant code will help..

Answer (score 0):

most likely there is fatal error produced by your php script and nothing is showed, because you turn error reporting off (which is good).

Search apache error.log for fatal errors produced by php. Position of error.log file is based on OS and your configuration, e.g. in linux it might be in /var/www/httpd/error.log

Comment: There is no fatal error , cause if there was any the back button wouldn't work either...

Comment: Did you check the log, or simply assumming, that there is no error ? Backbutton will work, fatal error may be produced on booking.php only when redirecting there by backbutton. The source you pasted is not helpfull at all, because html can not produce that kind of behaviour and you echo-ing some id retrieved from db, so I assume, that there is php code above that html, which stops the execution. Does booking.php require any input GET/POST variables ?

Comment: yes there are some code above this html that produce date and some other things they are working just fine . what i don't understand is why is this happening only in Safari on a MAC , and only happens when you try to back the page with touch pad

Comment: hm, that is strange ... I found possible explanation of this 'feature' :) http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1599476